# What files/directories does git ignore by default?

Tags: git, gitignore

I noticed that in a newly created git repo, directories like `__pycache__` or .`svn` are already ignored. I don't remember configuring git to ignore these directories. How can I view the list of patterns that are currently ignored by git? I'm using git v2.1.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that git ignores empty directories - it just cannot store them. Also you can check if there's global gitignore created in your system (`~/.gitignore_global`)

Comment: You're right, Maciej. Also, if all files in a directory are ignored (e.g. `*.pyc` files in `__pycache__`), the directory itself is effectively ignored.